# scrheadings ignored by document

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

I used to be able to get head/foot-ers with (perhaps a subset of) this set up, not anymore:

it displays only Foo, Bar and Baz on pages 1, 2 and 3, respectively.

Any suggestion as to what could be disabling it?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{keyfloat}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{refcount}
%\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{xwatermark}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\chead{XYZ}
\cfoot{\thepage /\pageref{LastPage}}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}

Foo

\clearpage

Bar

\clearpage

BAZ

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not load package `xwatermark` with

```
\usepackage{xwatermark}
```

It uses package `fancyhdr` which conflicts with `scrpage2` as you can see in the resulting error messages of your given code.

So with the following MWE

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{keyfloat}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{refcount}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
%\usepackage{scrpage2} % outdated

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xr}
%\usepackage{xwatermark}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\chead{XYZ}
\cfoot{\thepage /\pageref{LastPage}}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}

Foo

\clearpage

Bar

\clearpage

BAZ

\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image]

Comment: PS: but what if you need `xwatermark`?

Comment: Then do not use `scrlayer-scrpage` or `scrpage2`. Use `fancyhdr` instead.